# How can I implement tag filter and global tag search in Ant Design in React?

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

How to apply tag filter and global tag search in ant design in react ?

Any one implement tag search or filter in ant design, please give me good example related that with codepen implementation. search by name, id is working proper but stuck in tag filter and searching, I am getting data from Json and showing in data table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.